# How can I query CPU usage for a process in Linux at a specific moment in time?

Tags: linux, cpu-usage

I'm trying to figure out what the CPU usage of Firefox is at any given moment in time, and pipe that number to another script.

So, top is not the answer, since its output is in a chart and polluted with special characters.

I've also tried:

```
ps -eo pid,cp | grep $(pidof firefox)
```

But that gives CPU usage divided by CPU time, which is not the same that top or Gkrellm report.

So, how can I write a one-liner that gets the CPU usage of a particular PID?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. For me, `ps` and `top` show similar numbers. Are you running `top` with IRIX mode on or off? Can you show examples of how the output differs? What distro? How many cores?

Comment: Do you need CPU time or CPU usage as a percentage of a core (or the whole system)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Top can provide the information, and with some creative awk/grep usage, you can pull out the pieces you want.

top -b -n 1 | grep firefox | awk '{ totuse = totuse + $9 } END { print totuse }'

Comment: as baumgart mentioned you can add a watch to your command like this:
watch -n 1 'top -b -n 1 |awk "/firefox-bin/{ cpu+=\$9 } END { print \"firefox cpu usage: \" cpu\"%\" }"'

Comment: This line prints 0 even if Firefox isn't running: top -b -n 1 | grep firefox | perl -ne 'printf "%s\n", int((split /\s+/, $_)[8]);

Comment: It prints 0 because it's summing values.  If you want just one process (and you know there will only be one), you can shrink that perl stuff to `awk '{print $9}'`.  The full command becomes `top -b -n 1 | grep firefox | awk '{print $9}'`.

Comment: @baumgart  but this prints the cpu usage of the process over the life time and not for a given time interval like 1 sec or so.